# What is deliverbl in UCM ClearCase?

Tags: android-activity, clearcase-ucm, baseline

I am wondering about 'deliverbl', how important are they for historical purposes or during development? All I know is they are created during delivery and includes activies.

If i am exporting major baselines from Clearcase to different SCM, should I consider 'deliverbl' as major baseline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are representing **merges** (from a child stream to another stream), so:

- they should be considered, as they show the code "merged" (with potential conflicts resolved)
- but you might have more trouble to export the merge hyperlink which shows the *source* of the merge

I like to export those baselines because their naming convention shows the stream destination name, as well as the date of the deliver, so you are left with clues about a merge between two branches.

However, their are **unlabelled**, so you might:

- either need to convert those to a full baseline ([`cleartool chbl -full`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chbl.htm))
- or decide to not bother with them and leave those out of your export.