# clearcase; delivery and baselines

Tags: stream, clearcase, baseline

I don't know "clearcase" very much but I have to use it to deliver some developments from "dev" instance to test instance of a specific application.

1. Should I have to use a "dev" stream and a test stream for that  Suppose I have a code lets say test.sh which I should execute on test instance. Now DEV write version 1 of "test.sh" and deliver it to test On test stream, I can see test.sh and execute it. Let's say now version 2 of test.sh is release and deliver to test after version 3 of test.sh is released and deliver to test. On test, now the last version is version 3.
2. I would like to execute version 2 before version 3 in test. How can I do it automatically ? Do I have to use baselines ? How to automatically execute a baseline even if it is not the last one ? What is instead of "test.sh", I have a set of scripts ? Please notice that in my example, I have to execute version 2 before version 3 because my script suppose a certain state of my objects in test environment. If run version 3 without running version 2, it won't be ok.

Can someone explain me how I can do that with "clearcase" and give me some advices ?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to execute version 2 before version 3 in test. How can I do it automatically ? Do I have to use baselines ?

Yes: If each deliver is baselined, you would be using `baseline2` before `baseline3`. Make sure those baselines (set after each deliver to `test`) are full (see "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309)").

> How to automatically execute a baseline even if it is not the last one ?

By using a dedicated dynamic view for the test, in which you set the config spec:

```
element * baseline2
element /main/LATEST
```

Comment: Thanks Von. Can we automatically create a full baseline after deliver to test or do we have to go to test stream and create the full baseline manually ?

Comment: @NGM there is a deliverbl baseline produced for each baseline, but you need to convert it to a full one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19604066/6309

Comment: Thanks Von. Can we automatically create a full baseline after deliver to test or do we have to go to test stream and create the full baseline manually ? How can we automatically execute a script on test stream after deliver and full baseline ? Also I want to know - if we don't automatically execute a script on test stream and we have baseline 1, baseline 2 and baseline3 and we deliver them to test stream how do we practically ask to Clearcase to execute the script for baseline 1, then the one for baseline 2 and then the one for baseline 3 ? Where is the link between baseline and script ?

Comment: Excuse me. I also want to know if I can create those baselines in dev stream first. If yes, how can I see all the files in baseline 1 when I am now in baseline 3 for example ? Also is there a way in test stream to see if I have already executed the script for baseline 2 for example or do I have to do it myself ? That would tell me that the next time, I should execute script for baseline 3. I want to execute script related to a database et they should be executed in the order baseline 1, baseline 2 ... those scripts could have the same name.

Comment: @NGM not sure about the automation part, but "how can I see all the files in baseline 1 when I am now in baseline 3 for example": that would be using diffbl, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574208/6309.